# How to refresh WebView from code behind in .NET MAUI?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I want to refresh webview from the code behind like I can do it when I pressed F5 key. Is it possible execute F5 key command in the code behind for webview control in .NET MAUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the docs: `WebView` has a [Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview#reload-content) method

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
...
webView.Reload();
```

Comment: But I cannot use 'webView.Reload()' in webView.SizeChanged handler. I got 'system.invalidoperationexception 'a method was called at an unexpected time'. Actually I can't use it in any event handler method.

Comment: you didn't say anything about `SizeChanged` in your question.  You just asked how to reload the `WebView`

Answer (score 1):

I did this by adding RelayCommand. Passing reference to the WebView as command parameter. (I know it is wrong to do it). And calling Reload() method.

The command was bound to a button in my case. But you can try binding it to Event, using EventToCommandBehavior from CommunityToolkit.MAUI.

First EventHandler code is executed, then the Command.